# Ag grid using framework cell renderer keeps re-rendering on any store change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Trying to implement a custom cell framework renderer with React and it seems simple enough. Create the React component, register it with `frameworkComponents`.

The data that populates `rowData` is coming from my redux store. The custom cell renderer is a functional react component.

The issue is that because I'm using a frameworkComponent - a React component in my case - as a cellRenderer, it seems that any change in the data for the grid the I'm getting via `useSelector(selectorForMyData)` causes a re-render of my frameworkComponent, which on the browser, looks like a random, annoying flicker. The application is heavily wired into redux

Two questions:

1 - How come when I natively use ag grid to render this cell using a `AgGridColumn` without any custom cell renderers, it doesn't cause this re-rendering behavior on the same store changes? I have a click event bound to the main page that toggles a flag to false (in the case a snackbar alert was open).

2 - Is there any way to get around this? I've tried wrapping my `return` statement in the framework cell renderer component  with a `useMemo` with the `params` as a dependency, but that doesn't seem to work. Also tried making a `render` function via `useCallback` with the same idea as `useMemo` and that doesn't help either :/

Thanks

pseudo-code for situation:

```
App.tsx:

<MyAgGrid/>

MyAgrid.tsx:


const MyAgGrid = () => {
 const data = useSelector(selectorForData);
 return (
   <AgGridReact
     rowData={data}
     frameworkComponents={
       {'myCustomRenderer': CustomRendererComponent}
     }
     columnDefs={
       ['field': 'aField', cellRenderer: 'myCustomRenderer']
     } />
   );
};


CustomCellRendererComponent.tsx:

const CustomCellRendererComponent = (params) => {
  console.log("params", params) //logs on every redux store update
  return (
    <div>HELLO WORLD</div>
  );
};
```

The cells that are rendered via the `CustomCellRendererComponent` are re-rendered on any redux store change. I'm guessing it's due to `useSelector` causing the re-render on store changes, which is expected, but then it doesn't answer my first question.

EDIT:
I went "function as class" route shown [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/react/component-cell-renderer/) ("MyCellRenderer") and so far am not seeing the re-rendering issue, so I will stick with that for now even though it's god ugly. This leads me to believe my issue is trying to fit a React component/hooks, with its lifecycle nuances, as a cell renderer is causing problems. Still, I feel like there should be a way to prevent the behavior of constant re-rendering, otherwise it's a pretty useless feature

EDIT pt 2:
I dug deeper and while I haven't found an out of the box solution for it, I added  the `reselect` library to memoize some of my selectors. The selector I use to get `rowData` is now memoized, and I'm no longer seeing this issue. Will mark as answer in a few days if no one provides a better, ideally out of the box (with redux or ag grid), solution for it.

Comment: Adding the relevant code to your question would be helpful.

Comment: @EdLucas Definitely agree, I added a very dumbed down / pseudo code for it. It'd be a bit of work to get a whole playground set up for it w/ the redux boilerplate stuff and all :/ Not sure why my comment isn't tagging you, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in one of my edits. I figured it out, kind of.

I added the library `reselect` to the application, and it fixes the symptoms and I'm content with it going forward. It allows you to memoize your selectors, so that it only registers changes/"fires" (leading to a re-render) only if the any of the dependency selectors you hook it into changes/fires, so now, my grid doesn't "flicker" until the actual row data changes since my `selectorForRowData` is memoized!

I'm still uncertain why prior to using a `frameworkComponent` (React Component) as a cell renderer I wasn't seeing the symptoms, but I'm happy to just assume Ag-Grid has a lot of performance tricks that clients may lose when plugging in their own custom functionality, as is the case in a custom cell renderer.